# Server writing out javascript object as string instead of integer

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-forge

I have a weird problem which I can't solve right now.

My local site (homestead) is writing out javascript objects in the page like so

```
var carriageCosts = [{"id":1,"weight":0,"cost":12,"created_at":"2015-10-20 06:25:13","updated_at":"2015-10-20 06:25:13"}]
```

Weight and cost are integers. After deploying to digitalocean using forge it is being written out like so

```
var carriageCosts = [{"id":"1","weight":"0","cost":"12","created_at":"2015-10-21 02:49:37","updated_at":"2015-10-21 02:49:37"}]
```

Weight and cost are now strings!!

This is causing errors with the javascript. Has anyone seen this before? Some direction in solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Data is sent to blade view like so

```
return view('quote.create')
    ->with([
        'customers' => $customers,
        'sellPrices' => \App\SellPrice::all(),
        'coreCaps' => \App\CoreCap::where('available', 1)->get(),
        'threePhaseCostings' => \App\ThreePhaseCosting::all()->first()
    ]);
```

Blade view writes out the data

```
var carriageCosts = {!! $carriageCosts !!};
```

Weight and Cost columns in the database are both ints.

Development server is returning Eloquent objects with correct data types, i.e. ints are ints. Production server is returning Eloquent objects with incorrect data types, i.e. ints are strings.

There is some server configuration different but I can't find it...

Comment: So what code does generate it? And what is the exact data that is used to generate it?

Comment: If this is a problem, can't you just use `parseInt([string_value_here])` to change it back to an integer?

Comment: @jlam55555 that would be silly

Comment: @zerkms Why silly? (I don't use Laravel so I don't really know what the question is asking, but I thought the question was just about Integers turned into Strings)

Comment: @jlam55555 it would be silly to perform conversion twice instead of fixing the roots of the problem. "just about Integers turned into String" --- that's right. And that's why it's important to find out why it happens in first place, not pretend everything is fine.

Comment: @zerkms Oh okay. It's a suggestion though if you need it. And welcome to the SO community!

Comment: @jlam55555 unless I'm a member for almost 6 years, but thank you :-D

Comment: So have you tried to `var_dump` the original data?

Comment: I could just parseInt yes, but as zerkms said that isn't addressing the root problem. I'd like to know why localhost is writing out as integers but production server as strings! :)

Comment: @MurrayThompson suspect it's a php configuration difference somewhere. Try comparing configurations

Comment: The date strings are suspect too: "2015-10-20 06:25:13" is not a valid ISO 8601 format and may be treated differently by different browsers (if you are converting to Date objects using the Date constructor or Date.parse on the client).

Comment: Eloquent seems to be returning strings on the production server but correct datatypes on development server.

Comment: @zerkms Sorry, thought you were the OP. Murray, if you see this, welcome to the SO community.

Comment: @RobG I believe `T` is optional. Or is there anything else?

Answer (score 0):

In your `json_encode()` can use option `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`

```
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Reference [php json constants](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)

Comment: It's also solving consequences not the roots of the issue: http://ideone.com/4xmLZD since `json_encode` works fine if data is fine.

Comment: @zerkms yeah, probably right, need to catch when returned from db but I've seen this happen too with MYSQL INT in php